# Changing select_query to mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Here is the line of code that my `select_query` is being used in:

```
$result = select_query("tblaffiliatespending", "SUM(tblaffiliatespending.amount)", array("affiliateid" => $id), "clearingdate", "DESC", "", "tblaffiliatesaccounts ON tblaffiliatesaccounts.id=tblaffiliatespending.affaccid INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.id=tblaffiliatesaccounts.relid INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.id=tblhosting.packageid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblhosting.userid");
```

Here is the syntax it is using:

```
select_query($table,$fields,$where,$sort,$sortorder,$limits,$join)
```

You can view the docs on this here:  http://docs.whmcs.com/SQL_Helper_Functions

Can anyone figure out how to change the select_query into a normal mysql_query that I can use within my Smarty template system?  I've been trying out tons of different ways and all of them return a blank array...  Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but the query this code builds is the following:

```sql
SELECT SUM(tblaffiliatespending.amount) 
FROM tblaffiliatespending 
JOIN tblaffiliatesaccounts ON tblaffiliatesaccounts.id=tblaffiliatespending.affaccid 
INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.id=tblaffiliatesaccounts.relid 
INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.id=tblhosting.packageid 
INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblhosting.userid
WHERE affiliateid=$id 
ORDER BY clearingdate DESC
```